# How to deploy pure wear os standalone app inthe smartwatch for testing

Tags: android, wear-os, sony-smartwatch

I am new in developing wear-os apps and I am having trouble getting my standalone application into the smartwatch (Fossil Sport with wear-os v2.17)

- Android min SDK: 25, Target SDK: 29, Compile SDK: 29
- I've connected the watch via USB and the Android Studio seems to not recognize it.
- I've paired the watch with a physical phone (Pixel 3) and connected the phone via USB into the laptop. Android Studio recognizes the phone, but it shows a message saying that the phone is missing the watch feature.
- The watch has developer mode enabled and ADB Debug enabled.
- I also tried pairing the phone via Bluetooth with the laptop, Android Studio does not recognize this.

Any help on this is much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer Fossil watches only use USB for charging, not a data connection, so ADB over USB won't work. Use ADB over Wifi to the watch instead: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/debugging#wifi-debugging

Comment: Thanks, it did work, I tuned on Debug over WIFI on Developer Options, then use the ADB console to connect: adb connect [watch wifi ip]